Logstash is updating sincedb, but indices are not creating
I am collecting ALB logs from S3 into elasticsearch using logstash. For now, I wanted to collect more than one year of data from S3 and ingest into elasticsearch. I am creating indices for everyday with the name of index-name-*. When I start the logstash it's reading the logs and ingesting data into the elasticsearch but at some point, it stops creating indices but when I check the sincedb, it's updating properly. If I restart the logstash it's started to create the indices from the time which is updated on sincedb but indices prior to the date updated on sicedb also not created. I am using m7g.2xlarge instance and allocated 6GB of for logstash heap as well. Please advise on this issue.
